# Conduct a Speed Test of Internet Connection In an automatic manner

Tags: networking

I would like to conduct an extensive tests on my new internet connection using speedtest.net 
Is there some way that I can completely automate the process. 
The speed test is conducted at a fixed interval of time automatically and a spanshot of the screen is then taken and stored on my system.

Answer (score 2):

I found a good repository that does basically exactly what you're asking, but better (runs multiple tests, can run from the command line.)

I would recommend copying the code (python) from https://github.com/Janhouse/tespeed.

You can run this repeatedly using a [cron job](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cron), and easily email the results to yourself using the crontab file.

For easy step by step instructions, I found http://www.pythonforbeginners.com/code-snippets-source-code/command-line-speedtest-net-via-tespeed/